# Can inner class refer non finalvariable defined in outer class in Java 8

Tags: java

I have always thought that an inner class CANNOT refer non final variable defined in outer class.

But, when I write the following code, it compiles correctly and can be run in Intellij Idea.

Why does the following code work?

```
public class Outer {

    /**
     * non final variable greeting is used in inner class, non final is OK?
     */
    private String greeting = "Greeting1";

    /**
     * non final variable s is used in inner class, non final is OK?
     */
    public String doWork(String s) {
        class Inner {
            public String speak(String ss) {
                return greeting + "--- " + s + "---" + ss;
            }
        }
        Inner obj = new Inner();
        return obj.speak("Inner");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer obj = new Outer();
        //Can assign here.
        obj.greeting="Greeting2";
        System.out.println(obj.doWork("Outer"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, clearly you thought incorrectly. Why did you think that?

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585) and clarify your question.

Comment: @Sweeper there are `final` variable issue with inner class,but i can't reproduce when this problem would occur,thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) says:

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be declared final or be effectively final ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.

You most likely recalled/remembered an incorrect version of that. You might have mistook it as:

> Any **instance variable**, local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be declared final <s>**or be effectively final ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4))**</s>, or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.

`greeting` is a field (aka instance variable), so can be used in inner classes whether or not it is final or not.

`ss`, though it is a formal parameter, is *effectively final*, so it can be used in inner classes too. Note that the phrase "effectively final" has a formal definition in [§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), but informally, it just means "you did not reassign it another value in this method" in this context.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39889003/5133585) for why this restriction exists.